# How to get Eto.Forms add-in at Xamarin Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, xamarin, monodevelop, add-in, xamarin-studio

I can't find Eto.forms add-in at Xamarin Studio Community for Mac (6.0.1 build 9).

I read quick-start.
https://github.com/picoe/Eto/wiki/Quick-Start

Following it, I opened Add-in Manager, clicked Gallery tab and refreshed.
But, no add-ins in Add-in Manager Gallery.
Was it removed?
I need any helps.

[Add-in Manager Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GB7Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

The author of that Add-in has not updated it for Xamarin Studio/Monodevelop 6.x+

Ref: https://github.com/picoe/Eto/issues/527

```
+<AddinProject appVersion="5.9">
```

Ref: https://github.com/picoe/Eto/commit/60cd1472868bb81b92156aa9676db68e35aa6aea

Comment: Thanks very much... I'm sorry that I failed to make sure and my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

It has now been updated for 6.x, give it a try!

Note that XS 6.1.1 has a bug with the addin repo, so you have to add the 6.1 feed manually.  **UPDATE:** This now seems to be fixed in Xamarin Studio.